# Linq Converting String to List

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am getting the following error with my Linq query.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CTS.Domain.OCASPhoneCalls>'
```

I know what it means, but I'm unsure how to fix it.  Can someone help me with my query?  I'm really new to linq.

```
public List<OCASPhoneCalls> getPhoneLogs2()
{
    using (var repo = new OCASPhoneCallsRepository(new UnitOfWorkCTS()))
    {
        List<OCASPhoneCalls> phone = repo.AllIncluding(p => p.OCASStaff)
            .Where(y => y.intNIOSHClaimID == null)
            .Select(w => w.vcharDiscussion.Substring(0, 100) + "...")
            .ToList();                  
        return phone;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are selecting a `List<string>` but you are declaring a `List<OCASPhoneCalls>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting a `List<string>` but you are declaring a `List<OCASPhoneCalls>`, i assume you want to shorten the `vcharDiscussion`:

```
List<OCASPhoneCalls> phones = = repo.AllIncluding(p => p.OCASStaff)
    .Where(p =>  p.intNIOSHClaimID == null)
    .ToList();
phones.ForEach(p => p.vcharDiscussion = p.vcharDiscussion.Length > 100 ?
         p.vcharDiscussion.Substring(0, 100) + "..." :
         p.vcharDiscussion);
return phones;
```

**Edit**: "*I'm getting a null error. vcharDiscussion is coming up null*"

Then you need to check that:

```
phones.ForEach(p => p.vcharDiscussion = 
    p.vcharDiscussion != null && p.vcharDiscussion.Length > 100 ?
    p.vcharDiscussion.Substring(0, 100) + "..." :
    p.vcharDiscussion ?? "");
```

Comment: I do want to shorten vcharDiscussion and add ... to the end of it.

Comment: @hollyquinn: then this should work. You need to iterate them to modify the property.

Comment: I'm getting the following error message on return phones on this.  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CTS.Domain.OCASPhoneCalls>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: @hollyquinn: why have you changed the return type of the method, i thought that you want to return a `List<CTS.Domain.OCASPhoneCalls>`? I guess you have tested Habib's approach ;-)

Comment: @Time Schmelter you have return phones?? I didn't change it.

Comment: @hollyquinn: how does your method look like? The same as before: `List<OCASPhoneCalls> getPhoneLogs2()` Or is it `List<string> getPhoneLogs2()`? However, you see that the error message is now the opposite of your first error.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  I changed it back to the original.  I'm getting a null error.  vcharDiscussion is coming up null.

Comment: @hollyquinn: you need to check if its `null`, i have edited my answer. Note that i've used `p.vcharDiscussion ?? ""`(null-coalescing-operator) to treat `null` as `String.Empty`. If that's not desireed simply use `p.vcharDiscussion` at the end instead.

Answer (score 6):

You are selecting a single property with

```
.Select(w => w.vcharDiscussion.Substring(0, 100) + "...")
```

This would return you `IEnumerable<string>` and calling `ToList` would return you `List<string>` **NOT** `List<OCASPhoneCalls>`.

If you are returning formatted strings then your method return type should be `List<string>` like:

```
public List<string> getPhoneLogs2()
{
    using (var repo = new OCASPhoneCallsRepository(new UnitOfWorkCTS()))
    {
        List<string> phone = repo.AllIncluding(p => p.OCASStaff)
            .Where(y => y.intNIOSHClaimID == null)
            .Select(w => w.vcharDiscussion.Substring(0, 100) + "...")
            .ToList();                  
        return phone;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that he wants to return the objects but shorten the text property if necessary.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, hmm in that case OP has to iterate first and then modify the field like in your answer. +1

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm using this data to populate a GridView, it's now saying that other columns in the GridView do not exist.  The error message is DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'dtmDateCalled'.  Do I have to select those in my query?  Can you tell me how to fix that?  Thank you.

Comment: @Habib your way is working for me, except that my GridView can't find my other columns.  Do I have to select all columns in the linq query?  Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @hollyquinn, I guess your GridView is expecting a `List<OCASPhoneCalls>`, If that is the case, then use Tim's Answer. Do not change your method return type, Just use the query he has in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
`.Select(w => w.vcharDiscussion.Substring(0, 100) + "...")`
```

because select  it's projection and it will return  a list of string  and your method expect  to return

`List<OCASPhoneCalls>`